# Arabic Alphanumeric with spaces only regex

Tags: php, regex, arabic, phpbb3

I want to know the equivalent of the following, but for Arabic alphabet only:

```
$regex = '[A-Za-z0-9-[\]_+ ]+'
```

I tried:

```
$regex = '[ا-ئ0-9 ]+';
```

In which the first Arabic letter `ا` and the last one `ئ`. However, I have got the following error:

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: 
in file [ROOT]/includes/functions_user.php on line 1505: preg_match():
Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 6
```

Comment: Side comment: why don't you include hindu-arabic numbers? I would go for `~[\d\p{Arabic}[\]+_ -]+~u` since `\d` will match such numbers.

Comment: Because this should be used in a registration form and many of clients devices supporting Arabic with Arabic numbers not hindu.

Comment: See this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu–Arabic_numeral_system#Symbols) for more information :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if your Regex flavour supports `\p{Arabic}` or `\p{InArabic}`

try:

```
$regex = '[\p{Arabic}\d-\[\]_+ ]+'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but could you able to tell me about a resource that explain the code you regarded?

Comment: @sємsєм the above regex will match any character in the Unicode script “Arabic” `\p{Arabic}`, digit and this special characters: `-\[\]_+`

Answer (score 3):

You can begin to find the answer to your own question by taking a look and briefly reading the following:

- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script)

An equivalent regular expression would be the following:

```
~[\p{Arabic}\d[\]_+ -]+~u
```

Regular expression

```
[\p{Arabic}\d[\]_+ -]+     any character of: UTF macro 'Arabic',
                           digits (0-9), '[', '\]', '_', '+', ' ', '-'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
```

By adding the `u` modifier to the end of the regular expression, the Pattern strings are treated as UTF-16 and this also causes escape sequences to match unicode characters.

On a further note, by using `\p{N}` it will allow you to match any kind of numeric character in any script.

```
[\p{Arabic}\p{N}[\]_+ -]+
```

**Note**: It's more common to find a hyphen `-` placed first or last within a character class or choosing to escape it instead.